# Vector of medium sized objects concatenation and merging

Tags: c++, performance

I have a very [simple program](https://gist.github.com/RadimBaca/16d7c612dbd9082cd49de5df0dd85ad9) where I merge two vectors of 100byte objects (`SortRecord`).

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

constexpr size_t TUPLE_SIZE = 90;
constexpr size_t KEY_SIZE = 10;
constexpr size_t TUPLE_COUNT = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
constexpr size_t ARRAY_COUNT = 2;

using Record = std::array<uint8_t, TUPLE_SIZE>;
using Header = std::array<uint8_t, KEY_SIZE>;
using TimerClock = std::chrono::system_clock;

struct SortRecord {
    Header header;
    Record record;

    bool operator<(const SortRecord& record)
    {
        const uint64_t a = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(&header[0]);
        const uint64_t b = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(&record.header[0]);

        if (a == b)
        {
            const uint16_t c = *reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(&header[8]);
            const uint16_t d = *reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(&record.header[8]);
            return c < d;
        }
        return a < b;
    }
};

template<size_t tuplecount>
static auto CreateArray()
{
    std::array<std::vector<SortRecord>, ARRAY_COUNT> data_array;
    uint64_t hvalue = 0;
    srand(100);

    for (auto& data : data_array)
    {
        data.resize(tuplecount);
        hvalue = 0;
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&hvalue](auto& it)
        {
            *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&it.header[0]) = hvalue = hvalue + (rand() % 100);
        });
    }

    return data_array;
}

auto data_array = CreateArray<TUPLE_COUNT>();

// merge
std::vector<SortRecord> result1;
result1.reserve(TUPLE_COUNT * 2);
auto start = TimerClock::now();
std::merge(data_array[0].begin(), data_array[0].end(),
    data_array[1].begin(), data_array[1].end(),
    std::back_inserter(result1));
auto end = TimerClock::now();
std::cout << std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()) << " [ms]\n";
```

I have tried to compare it with a simple concatenation of these two vectors and surprisingly it has almost the same speed.

```
// concatenation
std::vector<SortRecord> result2;
result2.reserve(TUPLE_COUNT * 2);
auto start2 = TimerClock::now();
result2.insert(result2.end(), data_array[0].begin(), data_array[0].end());
result2.insert(result2.end(), data_array[1].begin(), data_array[1].end());  
auto end2 = TimerClock::now();
std::cout << std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end2 - start2).count()) << " [ms]\n";
```

I have tried it on MSVC 2017, and also on [gcc](http://quick-bench.com/T4osrkmlkK7MNCet5pAyT0VQEuc) and with very similar results. When I have tried to replace `SortRecord` with float or int then suddenly I get much [better results](http://quick-bench.com/4Ari3ZX2bcNsX85i-tEunMRF-zc) for concatenation.

What is the problem with the `SortRecord` variant?

Comment: You should include the definition of SortRecord.

Comment: are the vectors you are merging really sorted? I couldnt see it from the code. Then consider that both `merge` and `insert` are just of linear complexity, so not seeing a big difference should not be a surprise

Comment: ...and the canonical question: did you turn on compiler optimizations? if not, comparing runtimes is rather meaningless

Comment: OT: Your assignment of `SortRecord` would me hurt a bit less if you would use `sizeof *this`. However, I would prefer the `operator=()`. I wonder why you did overload it at all. The implicit generated `operator=()` should do as well.

Comment: @user463035818 yes, it is sorted. There is a `hvalue` variable in `CreateArray` which randomly incremented during each cycle.

Comment: @user463035818 I'm using /O2 in MSVC and -O3 in gcc

Comment: "There is a hvalue variable in CreateArray which randomly incremented during each cycle" it might be the case, but I dont see it, your `operator<` is not just comparing that `hvalue`, but to meet the precondition of `merge` the vectors need to be sorted with respect to the `operator<`

Comment: @user463035818 I've tested it in main and it is sorted:`for (auto i = 1; i < data_array[0].size(); i++)  if (!(data_array[0][i - 1] < data_array[0][i])) return 1;`

Comment: I'll take a wild stab and say that builtin types may have specializations for your platform that run faster than the generic struct type.  Without assembly though, this is a wild ass guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two effects that both scale linear with the number of elements to merge:

- elements have to be read and written
- in addition `merge` has to compare elements

Both contributions scale linear with the number of elements, but their dependence on the size of the elements appears to be different.

**`int` insert vs merge**

For small `int`s the overhead due to comparing the elements wins and you see `insert` outperforming `merge`.

**`SortRecord` insert vs merge**

Your `SortRecord`s are rather massive. In this case it seems that the major contribution is from reading and writing the elements and comparing them is only a minor contribution. (I am a bit puzzled why in your benchmark `merge` is actually 10% faster than `insert`, but lets call that insignificant ;).

One could speculate that it has some thing to do with cache and the fact that memory access actually does not scale linear. Anyhow, if you just make the `SortRecord` smaller, but keep the number of elements to merge, you [see the same difference as for integers](http://quick-bench.com/_JQRC3gyrZ0ToDPwlFhPzyYJheI).

Comment: Ok, it looks plausible. I was thinking similarly. I did several other tests and I have noted, that if I use /MDd instead of /MD in MSVC then the `SortedRecord` variant runs differently. In such a case, the `insert` two times faster which is really strange behaviour. I feel that the optimizer is some kind of black magic ...